# Fill area between axis and plot fill area (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, limit, fill, geom-area

I am using this code:

```
 library(tidyverse)
 set.seed(143)
 series <- data.frame(
   time = c(rep(2017, 4),rep(2018, 4), rep(2019, 4), rep(2020, 4)),
   type = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 4),
   value = rpois(16, 10)
   )
 plot1 <- ggplot(series, aes(time, value)) +
   geom_area(aes(fill = type))
 plot2 <- ggplot(series, aes(time, value)) +
   geom_area(aes(fill = type)) +
   scale_x_continuous(limits=c(2018, 2020), breaks=seq(2014, 2021, by=1))
```

For `plot2`, how can I expand the 'fill' between x=2018 and the y-axis? I would not like to see 2017 itself (as in `plot1`), but I would like to see this 'fill' between the y-axis (say x=2017.8) and x=2018.

I tried `limits=c(2017.8, 2020)`, but no luck.

**Edit**

This is what I am looking for:
[image]

Comment: I don't fully understand by what you mean by "expand the fill".  Please provide details of your ecxpected output.  Does `series %>% 
  filter(time > 2017) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(time, value)) +
      geom_area(aes(fill = type)) +
      scale_x_continuous(
      limits=c(2017, 2020),
      breaks=seq(2014, 2021, 1)
    )` come close to what you want?

Comment: Thanks. I would like ```plot2``` to be the same as ```plot1```, except with ```limits=c(2017.8, 2020)```, but if you do that, the area between the vertical lines x=2017.8 and x=2018 is blank instead of filled. I hope that clarifies it? Your solution unfortunately did not answer this question, but thank you for trying. I hope it is now clear what I mean.

Comment: @Limey - See edit of my question for the result that I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ggplot(series, aes(time, value)) +
  geom_area(aes(fill = type)) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(2017.8, 2020)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2018, 2021, 1))
```

Gives

[image]

`coord_cartesian()` includes *all* input data in calculations (smoothing, interpolation etc), produces the plot and then crops the resulting image as requested.  In contrast, `lims()`, `xlim()` and `ylim()` etc set points outside the requested limits to `NA` *before* performing calculations and constructing the plot.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for! Also thank you for explaining why this works. Gracias! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use expand:

```r
plot2 <- ggplot(series, aes(time, value)) +
  geom_area(aes(fill = type)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(2018, 2020), breaks=seq(2014, 2021, by=1))

plot2 + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

If you'd like to expand the scale by addition:

```
plot2 + scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(add = c(-0.2,0)))
```

Comment: Very nice suggestion, thank you, but this does not solve what I am looking for. If in this result, the x-axis can be from 2017.8 to 2020, then it would be perfect.

Comment: See edit of my question for the result that I am looking for.

Comment: I updated my answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Very close, but not yet completely. The -0.2 seems give the same result as -0.000001, for example. I was hoping to for less space between the y-axis and x=2018, like Limey's solution, but thank you very much! :)