# Histogram using scale_x_continuous() to start from 0

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, x-axis

I'm trying to create a histogram with tick marks at each bar. However, when I use `scale_x_continuous()`, the x-axis adjusted to the lowest number, which happens to be not 0. How can I make the x-axis start from 0? I tried `x_lim(0,20)` but it got over-ruled by `scale_x_continuous()`.

```
set.seed(1234)

dat <- as_tibble(sample(20, 100, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(value > 5)

ggplot(dat, aes(value)) +
  geom_histogram(color = "white", fill = "dark grey", binwidth = 1, boundary = -0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 20, 1))
```

Comment: Use the "limits = " option in the `scale_x_continuous()` call

Comment: add ` scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 20))`

Comment: @Dave2e I think it's better to use `coord_cartesian`.  This uses all the data to construct summaries and then "zooms" the plot.  `scale_x_continuous` , `xlim` and `ylim` (and similar) first *filters* the data and then constructs statistics, which can lead to misleading (or simply incorrect) summaries. So `coord_cartesian` has the behaviour that I believe most users would "expect".  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67266325/fill-area-between-axis-and-plot-fill-area-ggplot2) for another example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `xlim(0,20)` not `x_lim(0,20)`

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1234)

dat <- as_tibble(sample(20, 100, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(value > 5)


ggplot(dat, aes(value)) +
  geom_histogram(color = "white", fill = "dark grey", binwidth = 1, boundary = -0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 20, 1)) +
  xlim(0,20)
```

[image: ggplot2]`